# Focus textarea with caret after text in Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am currently writing a simple webapp to view tweets in the Android browser. 
I am using this code to focus the caret after the current text:

```
var oldContent = document.tweetBox.tweet.value;
document.tweetBox.tweet.value = '';
document.tweetBox.tweet.focus();
document.tweetBox.tweet.value = oldContent + to;
```

This code works flawlessly in Chrome, Fluid, Opera, Firefox en Safari.
The weirdest part is that the cursor starts blinking AFTER the 'to' text if I use my hardware keyboard but the text that I enter starts where I was typing before the JS above was executed.
If I use the soft keyboard the text entering starts at the start of the textarea.

p.s The javascript is part of a suggestion for followers, so if you start typing @gn it will suggest @gnur_nl in a seperate div and when you press enter this entry is chosen.

**Update:** This behaviour seems to be the result of a browser bug, [a bug report has been filed](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15245).

Comment: +1 for making me giggle with Carrot. Did you mean Caret

Comment: Hihi, just learned that it was called a "caret" a few days ago by a Dutch collegae who pronounced it like carrot :).

Comment: It's the correct pronunciation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a browser bug. Try setting the caret position manually:

```
var textArea = document.tweetBox.tweet, oldContent = textArea.value;
textArea.value = oldContent + to;
textArea.focus();
textArea.selectionStart = textArea.selectionEnd = textArea.value.length;
```

Comment: Yeah, most definitely a browser bug. However I would like a workaround. Unfortunately this doesn't solve it. Caret is blinking at the correct position, text input just starts at the wrong position.

Comment: @gnur: Fair enough. I have no Android device hence nothing to test on, so I can't help.

Comment: it is a major browser bug, even selecting a single character (space in my test) will show the space as selected in the textarea but typing will continue where I left off.

Comment: I am finding that .selectionStart is not accurate after a few changes to the field somehow in my case. It works fine in a browser just on crosswalk webview I am getting an issue for me. I am trying to stop the cursor jumping to the end of a text field when the user enters the caret at a particular position.

Answer (score 0):

```
setCaret = function(obj,pos) {
    // IE Support
    if (document.selection) { 

        // Set focus on the element
        obj.focus ();

        // Create empty selection range
        var oSel = document.selection.createRange ();

        // Move selection start and end to 0 position
        oSel.moveStart ('character', -obj.value.length);

        // Move selection start and end to desired position
        oSel.moveStart ('character', pos);
    }

    //standard browsers
    else if (obj.selectionStart || obj.selectionStart == '0') {
        obj.selectionStart = pos;
        obj.selectionEnd = pos;
        obj.focus ();
    }
};
```

and setting to the right positions

```
setCaret(document.getElementById("area"),document.getElementById("area").value.length);
```